# I want a script which always knows the latest media played from a folder and play the next one

Tags: bash

**E.g.:** I run

```
./latest /media/mytvshow/season1
```

And it'll automatically check the latest played file in that folder and play the next one in the sequence.

To do that I have planned about doing like this:

1- A **for** loop which will give a new timestamp to all files in the folder,minute by minute. This loop shall run only once (I haven't thought about any faster ideas). Something like

```
for file in `ls -l | tail -n +2 | cut -c 46-`
do
touch $file
sleep 1m
done
```

2- With timestamps correctly set, the script would run this everytime it is called

```
MEDIA=`ls -lt | cut -c 46- | head -2 | tail -1`
mplayer $MEDIA
touch $MEDIA
```

So I ask 2 things:

a. Am I doing using a good way to do this or is there a faster or better way?

b. The command `ls -l | tail -n +2 | cut -c 46-` seems to not be working. Why?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Two ideas: (1) Python will be less error prone, and (2) you could choose which file to play based on the filenames too, not only the modified times.  Or perhaps their creation times as well.  Lots of possibilities there...all of which are easily accessible in Python too of course.

Comment: I do not have mplayer neither I have mp3 files, so check if `ls -1t | xargs -I '{}' bash -c 'touch {}; mplayer {}'` is working for you or not

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with using a custom script to kick off playing the media, why not just put the last-played filename in a (predictably-named, hidden) file? e.g.

`echo $now_playing > .last-played`

Assuming you always want to play files in the order `Oldest, ..., Newest`  you can use `ls -tr` to get the filenames in the appropriate order, and use the contents of `.last-played` to track which file you played last.

EDIT: Here's an example of what I mean. It's hideous but seems to work

HINT: Change `play` function to do whatever you wish with the file to play.

```
#!/bin/bash

T=./.last-played

play () {
    echo "$@" > $T
    echo "mplayer $@"
}


# if we find no tracking data, this will be our default: the oldest file
next=$(ls -tr1 | head -1) 

if [ -f "${T}" ]; then
    # Found a tracking file: does it have a valid filename?
    lastplayed=$(cat ${T})
    if [ -f "$lastplayed" ]; then
        # It was a real file: find the next-oldest one
        lastf=""
        while read line; do
            if [ "x$lastplayed" = "x$line" ]; then
                next=$lastf
                break
            else
                lastf=$line
            fi
        done <<<"$(ls -tr1)"
    fi
fi

if [ "x" = "x$next" ]; then
    echo "Finished!"
    exit
fi
play $next
```

Comment: hello sanmiguel, thanks for your answer. I am a linguist, I know just a little bit of programming, so I have come with the idea of creating small, maybe even silly, scripts to simplify my daily routines as a form of practising basic programming. I confess that I understood just some parts of your code, so I am going to study it and put it to use and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Ivã, I'm glad you found my answer useful! Putting together scripts to simplify repetitive tasks is a great way to learn programming. Keep going, don't be afraid to experiment and, above all, enjoy it! Is there anything in particular you'd like some help with in my answer?